# algorithm for finding date in sorted array of dates

Tags: arrays, date, find

here is my problem.

I have a sorted array of dates that is stored in a circular buffer. I have a pointer to last date in buffer. There is a possibility that some dates are missing. Client requires a range of dates. If low limit date is missing, program should return first closest date that is higher then required one and vice versa for upper limit date.
Here is an example:

Dates in circular buffer (int[18]):
1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28
and if client wants from 8 to 23,
program should return 11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23.

I tried like this :
Notes:
- number between two stars is current date, and diff is number of steps to go to find 8.
- pointer can not be less then 0 or higher then 17.

```
{1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,*28*}, diff = -20
{*1*,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28}, diff = +7
{1,2,3,4,5,11,12,*13*,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28}, diff = -5
{1,2,*3*,4,5,11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28}, diff = +5 -> (5/2)+1=+3<br />
(if I detect that I will just go x steps forward and x steps backward I split x in half)
{1,2,3,4,5,*11*,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28}, diff = -3 -> (-3/2)-1 = -2
{1,2,3,*4*,5,11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28}, diff = 4
{1,2,3,4,5,11,12,*13*,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28}, diff = -5
{1,2,*3*,4,5,11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28}, diff = +5 -> (5/2)+1=+3
```

If we continue like this we will get 13,3,11,4 over and over again.

Notes:
- It is only coincidence that we get 11 here. When I use some real examples, with more dates,this algorithm jumps over some other 4 (or 3) numbers.
- Dates are stored in EEPROM of uC, so reading dates take a while, and I need to find date as quick as it possible (with minimum reads).
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Set p1 to be the start of the buffer, p2 to be the end. X is what you're looking for.

If the date of p1Date is after X, return p1. If p2Date is before X return p2.

Look at the midpoint between p1 and p2, m. If mDate is after X then p1=m else p2=m.

Repeat until p1=p2.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is good solution when dates are stored in RAM memory. Problem is that I have 12000 dates stored in EEPROM of some device, and reading just one date take me few seconds. Can this algorithm be changed in some way that it assumes that no date is missing, and tries to find it's position by submitting last date from required? Then, if no dates are missing (what is most usual case), algorithm would find a date in one iteration. Again, thank you for quick answer.